# Jenkins active choice parameter loses <scripts> in HTML

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I use Scriptler plagin and active choice parameters that return html. Now I need insert  section in that html. I try do it like this

```
if (!Settings.contains("ExtraDeployTargets"))
{
    return "";
}

html =
  """
<script>
    function Test(selectObject)
    {
        console.log("Hi");
    }
</script>

<label style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; display: inline;">
    Choose number of additional instances:
</label>
<select name="value" style="height: 30px; font-size: 14px; display: inline-block;", onchange="Test(this)">
    <option value="AdditionalInstancesCount=0">1</option>
    <option value="AdditionalInstancesCount=1">1</option>
    <option value="AdditionalInstancesCount=2">2</option>
    <option value="AdditionalInstancesCount=3">3</option>
    <option value="AdditionalInstancesCount=4">4</option>
    <option value="AdditionalInstancesCount=5">5</option>
</select>
  """

return html;
```

[image]

But function not work in HTML. Also in page HTML code absent onchange property and  section

[image]

The question is - "How insert script in HTML in JenkinsFile?"

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you use `"""` instead of `'''` if there's nothing to interpolate inside the string? Why don't you `return ''' ... '''` directly?

Answer (score 1):

See the ***Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter*** → *Groovy Script* inline help:

> If this script is used for any of the *HTML* choice types of an *Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter*, the resulting HTML output will be sanitized to remove everything but basic formatting, like `script` tags, unless the script runs outside the sandbox. This mode requires approval from a Jenkins administrator to prevent cross-site scripting (HTML) and arbitrary code execution (Groovy).

Comment: So the answer is, you have to uncheck **Use Groovy Sandbox** below of the Groovy Script input and approve every change.